# Failed to start minikube with virtualbox driver on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to start minikube with comand "minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox". Befora i install the VirtualBox 6.1.18 for Linux(ubuntu 20.04). but when i run the start command the shell throw a error. can anyone help me with that

thannks a lot!!!

```
 StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: creating: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:00.173843 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SVM_DISABLED, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=3900MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create: creating: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:00.172445 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SVM_DISABLED, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))

❌  Exiting due to HOST_SVM_DISABLED: Failed to start host: creating host: create: creating: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:
VBoxManage: error: AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:00.172445 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SVM_DISABLED, rc=NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005))
  Suggestion: Your host does not support virtualization. If you are running minikube within a VM, try '--driver=docker'. Otherwise, enable virtualization in your BIOS
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7074
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually caused by virtualization been disabled in the bios of your machine and not allowing VirtualBox to start properly . Usually you just need to enter your bios setup and enabling Secure Virtual Machine Mode
For details checkout this post https://appuals.com/fix-amd-v-is-disabled-in-the-bios-verr_svm_disabled/

Answer (score 1):

> Usually you just need to enter your bios setup and enabling Secure Virtual Machine Mode

just like you said. I have to enter in the advanced configurations of the motherboard's bios  and enable Secure Virtual Machine Mode.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in Admin powerShell
minikube delete
Minikube start